# Android Development View Proportionality

Tags: xml, android-layout

Hi all I am making a game for Android and I need help placing some Views on the screen such that they are proportional to the screen. Consider the following XML code for my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"    
              android:background="@drawable/background">

<ImageView android:src="@drawable/logo" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/logo" ></ImageView>

<FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="2">
    <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/buttons">
         <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/main_layout" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal">
            <ImageView 
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:src="@drawable/menu_start_button" 
                android:id="@+id/start_button">
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                    
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:src="@drawable/menu_tutorial_button" 
                android:id="@+id/tutorial_button">
            </ImageView>
         </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="bottom" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:id="@+id/option_buttons">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/option_sound" android:src="@drawable/option_sound" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:paddingRight="5dp" android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/option_vibrate" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/option_vibrate" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingBottom="5dp" android:paddingRight="5dp"></ImageView>
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/option_show_help" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/option_show_help" android:layout_height="wrap_content"android:paddingRight="5dp"></ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I want the logo (with the id `logo`) to take up the top 30% of the screen. The FrameLayout takes up the bottom 30% of the screen and has two buttons in the middle (wrapped in the ScrollView with ID `buttons`) and three option buttons that's supposed to be on the right side of the FrameLayout (but for some reason it's on the left side) aligned vertically. The `android:layout_weight` does not help me solve my problem as I would like to have these Views proportional to the screen. So is there an elegant solution to my problem or would I have to do some tricky magic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I did have to use the `layout_weight` attribute after all. I had to set the parent's `weightSum` property to 1 and then set all its child elements' `layout_weight` so that it's proportional to the aforementioned `weightSum`. For example, if the child element has to be 50% of the parent's height, I set its `layout_weight` to 0.5 and its `layout_height` attribute to 0dp.